# what is method to call the eclipse Save/SaveAs option programatically in plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I call save method in eclipse plugin development programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879218/how-can-i-call-save-method-in-eclipse-plugin-development-programmatically)

I am developing a plug-in and on click a button, I like to call the save method of eclipse or call the save button on eclipse toolbar.

What is the way to do it.