# Save an Eclipse editor programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am developing a plug-in.

On clicking a button, I'd like to call the save method of Eclipse or call the save button on Eclipse toolbar.

What is the way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.getWorkbench().saveAll(..)
```

should do the trick.

If you want to save the active editor, please try

```
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
IEditorPart editor = page.getActiveEditor();
page.saveEditor(editor, true /* confirm */);
```

Note that the elements in the navigation path may be null.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian,But its saving all open editor.I want to save only current (Active) Editor.Can you please tell me how can i achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

I use this to save dirty editors for one or more projects:

```
//Save all changes
    Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable() { // save all editors needs to be called by the ui thread!
        @Override
        public void run() {
            IDE.saveAllEditors(new IResource[]{prj}, true);
        }
    });
```

where `prj` is an IProject object.

hope this helps

bye

Answer (score 0):

I used -

```
IDEWorkbenchPlugin.getDefault().getWorkbench().saveAllEditors(true);
```

Comment: Note: that `IDEWorkbenchPlugin` is internal and should not be used.  If you don't have access to your window or page, you can fall back on `PlatformUI.getWorkbench()` which is API.