# Save dirty editors in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

We have developed an Eclipse RCP Applicatoin. We have a requirement to check for all the dirty editors and prompt the user to save the same before we launch our dialog.

Please let me know if we have any reusable dialog to achieve the same.

Thanks in Advance,
Harish

Comment: Please, try to be more specific. What have you tried? What kind of problems you have faced?

Comment: This related question may also be of help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556262/how-to-save-opened-editors-in-eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.saveAllEditors`:

```java
IResource [] resources = array of IFile, IFolder, IProject 

boolean ok = IDE.saveAllEditors(resources, confirm);
```

From the JavaDoc:

> Save all dirty editors in the workbench whose editor input is a child
>   resource of one of the IResource's provided. Opens a dialog to prompt
>   the user if confirm is true. Return true if successful. Return false
>   if the user has canceled the command.

Answer (score 1):

`PlatformUI.getWorkbench().saveAllEditors(confirm);`

Saves all dirty editors in the workbench. Opens a dialog to prompt the user if confirm is true

Source: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/95433/ and javadoc